# Dropdown Alphabetical Order : Except First Row - jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm listing by alphabetical order with jQuery and in different languages, it works perfectly, except that the first Row/item "Select the category" is also listed by alphabetical order, I would like it to stay at the top, always first. "Select the category" is of course the only one with no Value. Is there any solution?

```
<!-- Group -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname"><?php echo $this->lang->line('category');?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="span12" name="catagory" id="catagory">
                <option value="" ><?php echo $this->lang->line('select_the_category');?></option>
            <?php
                $lang_code = $page_data['lang_code'];
                echo $lang_code;
                foreach ($page_data['catagory'] as $key => $value) {
                    $value = (array) $value;
                    echo '<option value="'. $value['event_type_id'] .'">'. $value['event_type_name_'.$lang_code] .'</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- // Group END -->
```

jQuery

```
var mylist = $('#catagory');
var listitems = mylist.children('option').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the php `usort` function on `$page_data['catagory']` and remove jQuery sorting.

Customized usort:

```
usort($page_data['catagory'], function ($a, $b) use ($lang_code) {
    $idx = 'event_type_name_'.$lang_code;
    return strcmp($a[$idx], $b[$idx]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the "Select the Category" option has no value, you can filter it out of the sort function and only sort `options` with a value.

```
var mylist = $('#catagory');
var listitems = mylist.children('option').filter(function(){return $(this).val() != "";}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/jzdj0kLh/